# Chrome dev tools and Ruby to login, establish valid session, and scrape jsp site

Tags: ruby, jsp, google-chrome-devtools, screen-scraping, mechanize

STACK EXCHANGE POST

**Background:**
I'm playing a simulation game written in jsp and javascript.  The UI is terrible for gathering data so I want to scrape it out of the html behind the scenes.

The application is all written in jsp and javascript.  Lots of tooltips and pop-ups storing valuable information that cannot be easily collected.

Based on my research, the following tools seem to be promising:
[*Ruby,  Nokogiri, Mechanize, Rubygems, Typhoeus*]

Here's what I want to try and do (I'm no expert in any of these areas, especially the Chrome dev tools though I'm learning a lot).  So, I'm not exactly sure what information the community needs from me to help, yet I don't want to bombard this post with TMI.

**Objective:**
1. After manually logging into the site using Chrome, I want to identify all relevant parameters (from chrome dev tools??) and information a Ruby script will need to connect to the web site impersonating me.

2. After having logged in successfully, use Ruby to make jsp calls and receive the html behind the scenes.
3. Using something like Nokogiri, traverse and parse the html and store information in a .csv file for later analysis with Excel.

**Challenges**
1. There is so much information in the chrome dev console, that I don't know what is relevant and what is not.
2. Not sure if I need to be making jsp calls or using the js? calls, etc.

The URL for the login page is(actual name has been changed): 
http://vt453R.nottherealname.net:8766/gl/gamecenter5/Login.jsp

Here is the header information I pulled from the dev tools (network, headers).  Note, cookie data not real.

```
Remote Address:xx.xx.xx.156:8766
Request URL:http://vt453R.nottherealname.net:8766/gamecenter/register/gamecenter5/Register
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:24
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:JSESSIONID=4543435FBC573AAEF5837249DA439857; JSESSIONID=A6FFA6A2984452C4987C33ADC987A888
Host:vt453R.nottherealname.net:8766
Origin:http://vt453R.nottherealname.net:8766
Referer:http://vt453R.nottherealname.net:8766/gl/gamecenter5/Login.jsp
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
action:checkRegistration
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Length:8
Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 27 Feb 2015 18:03:41 GMT
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=40776C5A23042848FKIFEKSKE3BEB477E; Path=/gamecenter/; HttpOnly
```

If this is the wrong approach, I'm open to writing a script that creates it's own session and operates with that, but I need to get past this hurdle first.

This is the source code for the login page, which might be helpful.

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >
<title>This is a title page for gamecenter</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" >
function registerTeam(){
document.loginForm.action="../../../gamecenter/register/gamecenter5/Register";
document.loginForm.submit();
}
function loginUser(){
document.loginForm.action="../../../gamecenter/authenticate/gamecenter5/Login";
document.loginForm.submit();
}
function set_time_zone(){
if(document.getElementById('timeZone')){
var current_date = new Date( );
var gmt_offset = current_date.getTimezoneOffset( );
gmt_offset = gmt_offset * -1;
document.getElementById('timeZone').value = gmt_offset;
}
}
function disableBackButton(){
window.history.forward();
}
setTimeout("disableBackButton()", 0);
onload = set_time_zone;
function gotoPasswordField(e){
unicode=getPressedKeyCode(e);
if(unicode==13){
document.getElementById("password").focus();
}
}
function gotoAuthenticate(e){
unicode=getPressedKeyCode(e);
if(unicode==13){
loginUser();
//document.getElementById("password").focus();
}
}
function getPressedKeyCode(e){
var unicode=e.keyCode? e.keyCode : e.charCode
return unicode;
}
function checkRegisterTeam(){
var params="action=checkRegistration";
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "../../../gamecenter/register/gamecenter5/Register",
data: params,
success: function(res){
if(res=="Disabled"){
$("#register").removeClass( "green-button");
$("#register").addClass("button_disable");
$("#register").attr('disabled','disabled')
}
}
});
}
function detectBrowser(){
var detectBrowser = navigator.sayswho= (function(){
var ua= navigator.userAgent, tem,
M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];
if(/trident/i.test(M[1])){
tem=  /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
return 'IE '+(tem[1] || '');
}
if(M[1]=== 'Chrome'){
tem= ua.match(/\bOPR\/(\d+)/)
if(tem!= null) return 'Opera '+tem[1];
}
M= M[2]? [M[1], M[2]]: [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
if((tem= ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i))!= null) M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]);
return M.join(' ');
})();
var browserVersion = parseInt(detectBrowser.split(" ")[1]);
if((detectBrowser.split(" ")[0]=="Firefox" && browserVersion<20) ||
(detectBrowser.split(" ")[0]=="Chrome" && browserVersion<33)  ||
(detectBrowser.split(" ")[0]=="Safari" && browserVersion<5) ||
(detectBrowser.split(" ")[0]=="MSIE" && browserVersion<9) ||
(detectBrowser.split(" ")[0]=="IE" && browserVersion<9)){
document.loginForm.action="detectBrowser.jsp";
document.loginForm.submit();
}
}
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/login.css" type="text/css" >
</head>
<body onload="checkRegisterTeam();detectBrowser();">
<form method=post action="detectBrowser.jsp" name="detectBrowser" id="detectBrowser">
</form>
<ul class="outer">
<li class="inner">
<center>
<form method=post action="GLAuthenticateUser" name="loginForm" id="loginForm">
<center>
<ul id="image">

<li id="banner">

<img alt="" src="images/banner.jpg"/>

</li>
</ul>
</center>
<center>
<ul  id="outerBox">
<li>
<ul  id="loginFields">
<li  id="label">  Login Id : </li>
<li  id="login_title" >  <input type=text name="loginId"  id="loginId" class="bgcolor" onkeypress="gotoPasswordField(event)" /> </li>
</ul>
<ul  id="loginFields">
<li  id="label">  Password : </li>
<li  id="login_title" >  <input type=password name="password" id="password"  class="bgcolor" onkeypress="gotoAuthenticate(event)"/> </li>
</ul>
<ul  id="loginButton">
<li>

<input class="green-button leftButton" id="register" type=submit name=register value=Register onClick="registerTeam()"/>
<input class="green-button rightButton" id="login" type=submit name=button value=Login onClick="loginUser()"/>
<ul style="clear:both"> </ul>
</li>
</ul>
<input type=hidden id="timeZone" name = "timeZone" />
</li>
</ul>
<ul class="footer">
<li> </li>
</ul>
</center>
</form>
</center>
</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wanted to include my first stab at this, which did pull the html, but the response was essentially, hey, you aren't logged in... hence the need to imitate session:

Comment: I used nokogiri after calling the url with a servlet name and variables appended at the end.  Some key snippets below.

    page = open("#{ACC_FINANCE_URL}")
    file = File.open("#{FIN_DATA_SUBDIR}/financial_data_scrape.html", 'w')
    file.write(page.readlines)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Let's see... you haven't written any code, and you want us to tell you how to do it? That's not what we do, instead we help you fix code you've written. As for processing JavaScript code, you're going to get little help from Mechanize or Nokogiri except in the case where the JavaScript source itself is of use to you. Turn off JavaScript in your browser and look at the page and its source. What you see is what Mechanize would see. If the information you need is there then you can proceed with Mechanize/Nokogiri. If not you'll need to use Watir or a similar tool.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome!  Let's see...  I actually have written code.  Some of it is in my first comment, but I'm limited in the number of characters I can post.  Additionally, I'm obviously incapable of mastering the mini-markup for code snippets as that failed.

On the contrary, I don't believe I've asked for anyone to write my code for me, surely that would be presumptuous.

On the other hand, I clearly haven't done a good job of articulating a question concisely enough.  I'll try again in a bit.